# Is there a precisely formulable obstruction for the tangent bundle being a Lie algebra bundle?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, lie-algebroids, cotangent-bundles

Although vector fields (which are sections of the tangent bundle) form Lie algebras, the bundle itself, as far as I know, almost never carries Lie algebra structure; that is, in general, I believe, there is no map $[\_,\_]:TX\times_XTX\to TX$ over $TX\to X$ that would induce brackets on vector fields.

Although I have heard that this non-existence is the reason why people study various kinds of algebroids, I must confess I have no idea why exactly such a bracket does not exist in general. It must have to do with integrability somehow but I don't know how. I only vaguely remember that some sort of algebroids produces a cohomology class that can be viewed as an obstruction to something I do not really remember.

Does all this make sense at all? Can anyone point to a reference where such obstructions are described in detail?

Comment: May be a related post could be the following  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351116/vector-valued-2-forms-which-satisfy-jacobi-identity

Comment: Yes it is related, although there might be Lie brackets that do not relate to the "standard" bracket on vector fields

Comment: Yes. But there is no a lie bracket structure on fibers which induce the standard lie algebra structure on vector firlds because the standard lie bracket is not a tensorial 2- linear map.

Comment: @AliTaghavi My question is just this - why? Is there a calculable obstruction to this?

Comment: I was thinking to a related question some times ago. I asked it at RG as follows  https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_Lie_Algebras_determine_the_structures_of_vector_bundles2